# Verification of a Conditional expectation

Tags: conditional-probability

I need to check if the following formula is correct.

$$ \mathrm{E}(Z \vert X=x)=\sum_{y} \mathrm{E}(Z \vert X=x,Y=y)\mathrm{P}(Y=y \vert X=x) $$

Just as a reference, Law of total expectation states that $\mathrm{E}(Z)= \sum_{x} \mathrm{E}[Z \vert X=x]\mathrm{P}(X=x)$

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It helps readability to format using MathJax (see FAQ). Also, can you share what you have tried? Did you provide enough information? Regards

Comment: anyone can help me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that all that was done was to condition $(Z|X)$ itself on $Y$. So as long as the expectation of the twice-conditioned interior is taken against all $Y|X=x$ then that outermost conditioning should drop and we are back where we started. This is sometimes called [the law of iterated expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation#Iterated_expectations_with_nested_conditioning_sets).